# NuGet - Messing up .csproj File

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package, csproj

Recently, when I attempt to update a package to the latest version (from within VS) NuGet will update the packages.config file and do one of two things:
Remove the reference to the assembly completely from the .csproj file
OR
Leave the old reference, without updating the version numbers.

It's only for one specific package, for all other packages it works just fine. Has anyone encountered this or know where I should start diving in? Manually updating my .csproj files all the time is getting old.

Comment: What is the package that is causing this?  Sounds like they messed something up.

Comment: It's an internal package. I uninstalled the package manager and reinstalled it (not for the first time) but it seems to be okay now.